# Install Windows Server 2016 on Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox, windows-server-2016

I am trying to install Windows Server 2016 on Virtual Box, and while moving forward I got stuck with this:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>
```

This came after Windows was trying to open, asked me to put administrator password, and after I entered the password this came out, and I don't know what I should do.

Can anyone can help me get past this problem?

Comment: This is expected behavior if you install the core version of windows server 2016. The core version is nothing more than this. No start menu, only command prompt and powershell. You can launch programs though.

Comment: Thanks, how can I launch windows? any advice?

Comment: You will have to reinstall Windows Server 2016 and select the **Server with Desktop Experience** version, as WS2016 does not support converting from core to Desktop Experience (GUI) version, or vice versa.

Comment: Its working. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Yea, this IS Windows Server. It's not an error. You need to clearly read the description of the versions the installer presents you with, and perhaps do some research online if you need more information.

Answer (score 4):

You have installed the core version of Windows Server 2016, which is essentially a boiled down version of the Desktop Experience version, and does not contain graphical management tools such as Server Manager.

The ability to convert between the core and GUI (Desktop Experience) versions was removed in Windows Server 2016, and so you will have to reinstall the operating system and select the **Server with Desktop Experience** version during installation.

> Unlike some previous releases of Windows Server, you cannot convert
>   between Server Core and Server with Desktop Experience after
>   installation. If you install Server Core and later decide to use
>   Server with Desktop Experience, you should do a fresh installation.

[Install Server Core](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/get-started/getting-started-with-server-core)